# Vim multiline regex gives overlapping matches

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I was surprised when I noticed that my greedy multiline regex was giving overlapping matches in Vim.  The regex is designed to match an entire block of text, or consecutive non-blank lines.

The regex apparently matched everything I expected it to (highlight looked correct), but when using [`n`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#n) to skip to the next match instead of skipping to the next block, it went to the next line in the current block.

Here is the regex I was using (equivalent to `(.+\n){1,}` for most regex engines):

```
\(.\+\n\)\{1,}
```

This should match at least one non-empty line, and as many consecutive non-empty lines as possible, here is an example text file:

```
block 1
some stuff
more stuff

block 2
foo bar
baz qux
```

After applying this regex (<kbd>/\(.\+\n\)\{1,}</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the two blocks are highlighted correctly, but I expect there to be only two matches of the regex, one for each block.  However when I press <kbd>n</kbd> to advance to the next regex match it appears that each non-empty line matches the regex, so my cursor would start on the first line, <kbd>n</kbd> would take it to the second line, then third, then to the start of block 2 etc.

**How can I change my regex so that I see the expected behavior of each block being a single match so that <kbd>n</kbd> advances to the next block, instead of the next line?**

I am also interested in knowing if this behavior is in the documentation somewhere, or if there is an option to change this behavior.  Note that when using the same regex in a search/replace the behavior is what I expect (replacement would only be applied twice, once for each block).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following regex seems to work:

```
\(\%^\|^\n\)\zs\(.\+\n\)\+
```

Explanation:

```
\(             # start of group
  \%^          # beginning of file
    \|         # OR
  ^\n          # a blank line
\)             # end of group
\zs            # start matching here
\(.\+\n\)\+    # at least one non-blank line
```

By using the [very magic](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) option the length can be reduced a bit:

```
\v(%^|^\n)\zs(.+\n)+
```

Looking forward to seeing if anyone can come up with a shorter solution!

zigdon's answer helped me to understand better why the behavior is the way it is.  When <kbd>n</kbd> is used to jump to the next match it searches for the first match of the regex from the cursor's current position, even if the next matching position was included in the previous match.  This is why anchoring the regex to the start of the block appears to be necessary.

Thanks to Nolen Royalty for helping me get rid of an unnecessary lookahead in the first group.

Comment: As far as I can see `\(\%^\|^\n\)\zs\(.\+\n\)*` accomplishes the same thing.  It's still frustratingly long though.

Comment: @NolenRoyalty With yours you will match some empty lines (zero-width match) if there are several consecutive empty lines, but it did lead me to `\(\%^\|^\n\)\zs\(.\+\n\)\+` which doesn't have the same problem.  Still pretty ugly!

Answer (score 2):

Since your match says "match one or more non-empty lines" it can certainly match multiple times within the same paragraph. To fix this, you can specify that the cursor should be placed at the *end* of the match - the means the next match will start from the end of the paragraph. You can do this with the `\zs` zero-width character, available in vim:

```
\zs     Matches at any position, and sets the start of the match there: The
        next char is the first char of the whole match. |/zero-width|
```

So your match will become:

```
\(.\+\n\)\{1,}\zs
```

Comment: This allows me to jump to the end of each block which is nice for how simple the regex is, but I would like to have the entire block contained in the match if possible.

Comment: The block would be contained in the match, just the cursor will be positioned at the end of it. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: What I mean by "contained in the match" is that if you were to use the same regex in a search/replace, everything contained in the match would be replaced.  Another equivalent meaning would be "the text that is highlighted".